# How do you describe the “growth／improvement” of “rights" (i.e. 权利）?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests

How do we describe the growth of “rights” （or more colloquially in English the "extension of rights' (e.g. the extension of women's rights, etc.)? Is it 女性权利的:

- 发展？
- 增加？
- 提高？
- 扩大？

Let me know what you think is best for the situation! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend. Here are the number of results:

- "权利的增加" 939,000
- "权利的扩大" 539,000
- "权利的提高" 333,000
- "权利的发展" 91,900

Answer (score 1):

女权的发展 and 女权的提高 would make sense depending on what you are trying to describe.

女权的发展 - development of women rights
女权的提高 - rise of women rights

I'm assuming you are seeking for rise of women rights?